# Show XML HTML Code in a Android Webview

Tags: android, html, webview

It sounds stupid, but I like to show HTML Code in a Android Web-View. Howto do it ?

I tried already, which wasn't a success:

- loadDataWithBaseURL with mymetype="text"
- I added a textarea into my webpage and showed the HTML in that area.

Answer (score 0):

Show html code in android WebView is same as show html code in html.
So you should replace the html special characters.

```
< ->    &lt;
> ->    &gt;
& ->    &amp;
```

Comment: Ok. But I have hundreds of characters. Thats not an elegant solution. I found a way with <code> Tag. I am just testing, if it does the right thing.